# How disable need to sudo? Setting root to admi, sudivo, and disabling SIP didn't work

Tags: macos, terminal, root, sudo, osx-elcapitan

I am having to type "sudo" before most terminal commands, and am also getting EACCES errors sometimes even when using sudo when chained to a secondary file/folder.

I've done the standard setting of root user to admin, added my username with all permissions in visudo, and successfully disabled SIP. It may have to do with permissions I may have changed when I first got my Mac years ago.

Does anybody have any ideas as to what could be wrong?

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these solutions worked as things are. Ended up wiping my computer's hard drive and permissions settings went back to normal.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you use `sudo command1`, you also encountered permission denied. It's because the command1 will invoke another process which don't have root prividge. In this situation you can put command in a script, and use `sudo bash script`, or `su` to change to root user. And sometimes `sudo filename` also permission denied, it's that you not have the x priviledge, you can `sudo chmod 744 filename`, then execute the command.

methods to avoid type sudo passward every minutes.

**method 1** recomended. [sudo -i](https://askubuntu.com/a/147275/582516)

**method2** use `sudo visudo` or `sudo vim /etc/sudoers` and put this in it. this will make username user neednot to pass passward when use sudo.

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

you can refer here for [config for one command](https://askubuntu.com/a/39294/582516)

hope helps.

Comment: I added: boblikesoup ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL 
to the bottom of the visudo and checked to confirm it saved. I am still getting EACCES errors without sudo and sometimes even with sudo.

Comment: you have to use boblikesoup ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: Added and still not working :\
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/boblikesoup...

Comment: If I sudo -i it wants to install meteor which I already have.

I've checked sudo visudo with and without sudo -i and it shows same file with the line "boblikesoup ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" at the end.

Comment: I am doing this in and it's re-installing stuff I already have no matter where I run sudo -i from or which folder I navigate to after: "Installing a Meteor distribution in your home directory.
Downloading Meteor distribution" Don't think it should be doing that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127372/discussion-between-kris-roofe-and-boblikesoup).

Answer (score 1):

Log in and open your terminal app. Run these two commands:

```
sudo echo >> /etc/sudoers
sudo echo "$(id -u -n) ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

Now you can run sudo without a password.  Do normal stuff under your regular account and when you want to run as root for a while do:

`sudo bash`

Comment: I am getting Permission Denied on those commands. Ran them after 'sudo -i' and am still having to sudo + password

Answer (score 1):

macOS includes a "root user" that can be enabled using Directory Utility.  Have a look at the following article from Apple: [Enabling and using the "root" user in OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012).  The article, while not explicitly saying it, implies that using the root user *is* the same thing as `sudo`.

The Apple article includes some warnings about use of the root user, but if you think about it, it's no more risky than deliberately disabling the password required by `sudo`.  Either way you're creating an unrestricted path to root-level functions, so do be careful about it!